# How to recover file deleted with NerdTREE

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, nerdtree

I accidentally deleted an important file using NerdTree's menu system. How do I recover it?

I've tried looking in my trash bin and I turned off the vim option to save swp files.

Comment: Vim can't help you. What is your OS? But note that you are likely screwed. Read The Tao of Backup, then learn how to use Git or another versioning software with an off-site repository.

Comment: Yeah I ended up just pulling down the file from git and rewriting the lost work.

Comment: This happened to me to when creating a folder. Just wiped everything for me without warning. Sucks

Answer (score 2):

[Not a direct answer to that Question, but relevant to that topic.]  Here is a workaround that I implemented for my use, to avoid accidentally deleting files in Vim/Neovim.

1. Make a backup copy, then edit your "fs_menu.vim" file. On my computer:

`~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim`

Uncomment this line:

`call NERDTreeAddMenuItem({'text': '(d)elete the current node', 'shortcut': 'd', 'callback': 'NERDTreeDeleteNode'})`

and comment out this line (prepend a double quotation mark):

`"call NERDTreeAddMenuItem({'text': '(d)elete the current node', 'shortcut': 'd', 'callback': 'NERDTreeDeleteNode'})`

That helps prevent you from accidentally deleting files, etc., in NerdTREE by removing the `(d)elete ...` menu item.

2. Make a "trash" folder:

`~/.Trash`

3. Now, when you want to delete a file, use the usual NerdTREE `m` menu command and `(m)ove` the file to your trash folder, by editing the path displayed; e.g.

`NERDTree Menu. Use j/k/enter and the shortcuts indicated`
`==========================================================`
`(a)dd a childnode`
`> (m)ove the current node`
`(c)opy the current node`
`(l)ist the current node`

`Rename the current node`
`.==========================================================`
`Enter the new path for the node:`
`/home/victoria/new3`

Change that path (in my case, my user name / home directory) to:

`/home/victoria/.Trash/new3`

and press `Enter` to move that file to that trash directory.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux I'd use extundelete tool — it works very good for me, so if it's the case and it's ext* FS:

```
extundelete --restore-file=path_relative_to_fs_root /dev/sdxx
```

Note that you have to unmount partition so if it's on root partition you'd have to use liveCD.

On windows there is also plenty of this kind of tools. I'm not Windows man, but maybe it would help you: https://datarecovery.wondershare.com/deleted-recovery/ntfs-undelete-alternatives.html

Anyway HURRY UP! The longer you use the filesystem, chances for recovering file decrease.